# Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 cannot access certain web sites

Tags: internet, ubuntu-studio

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1, I no longer can access certain websites. I know that similar questions have been asked a number of times, but I'm still stuck. I hope somebody here can help. Thank you in advance.

Some websites work fine (e.g. dmi.dk, peterbirch.dk etc).
Others return an error like "server IP address could not be found" (e.g. gnome.org, ubuntu.com or dr.dk)

I've checked the connections and the settings, and everything seems to be correct. Another desktop pc wired to the same router works perfectly well, as does my laptop through the wireless connection. The wire itself is okay - I checked that too.
There is no proxy and no firewall.

*Running resolve.conf shows this:*

```
peterbirch@peterbirch-10vtcto1ww:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

*iptables give us:*

```
peterbirch@peterbirch-10vtcto1ww:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

*nslookup for ubuntu.com:*

```
peterbirch@peterbirch-10vtcto1ww:~$ nslookup ubuntu.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find ubuntu.com: SERVFAIL
```

*A dig also for ubuntu.com:*

```
peterbirch@peterbirch-10vtcto1ww:~$ dig ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 19479
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ubuntu.com.                    IN      A

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 22 12:59:23 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

To me, this is more or less like abracadabra, and I have no idea what to do with this information. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Added info:
Discover tells me, that it can't look for updates because of a "failure resolving ubuntu.com". Perhaps this suggests a DNS problem?

Comment: It is definitely a DNS problem. What service are you using? Likely dnsmasq. Try directly using an external DNS, like the one your ISP suggests or 8.8.8.8

Comment: It definitely suggests a DNS problem. Try the same `dig` with an external nameserver: `dig ubuntu.com @9.9.9.9`. If that works, _your_ DNS is screwed up!

Comment: @DougSmythies: I tried 8.8.8.8, which gave this: "The server at 8.8.8.8 is taking too long to respond". I don't know how to find out which DNS service I am using.

Comment: I tried dig ubuntu.com @9.9.9.9 and it seems to work fine. So my DNS is screwed up. Do you know any way for me to "screw it down" again?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Doug Smythies, Auspex and others on the Internet, I've solved the problem.
First I tried using an external DNS, added to the Networks Manager through the GUI on the desktop taskbar. It worked, but I still wanted to know what happened to my local DNS. After a long time fiddling around with different cli commands, I found a broken symlink, which I fixed like this:

```
    peterbirch@peterbirch-10vtcto1ww:~$ cd /etc/

    peterbirch@peterbirch-10vtcto1ww:~$ sudo ln -sf ../run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf resolv.conf
```